# Search by start with not containing letter

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, search

I'm trying to implement a search function. But it's searching by containing letters, and I want to make it search by the beginning letter. 
Can any one help me?

Here is my existing code:

```
jQuery.expr[':'].contains = function(a, index, obj) {
        return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase()
            .indexOf(obj[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
    };

    function funnelInputSearch(thisSearchType) {
        var clientSearch = document.getElementById(thisSearchType),
            thisSearchTypeSelector = $('#' + thisSearchType),
            s = clientSearch.value;
        thisSearchTypeSelector.closest('.tab-pane').find('[class*="itemsList-"] .field-label-wrap').show();
        thisSearchTypeSelector.closest('.tab-pane').find('[class*="itemsList-"] .field-label-wrap:not(:contains("' + s + '"))').hide();
    }
    $('.funnel-input-search input').on('keyup', function () {
        var thisSearchType = $(this).attr('id');
        funnelInputSearch(thisSearchType);
    })
```

Here is the Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5u373deu/6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to add a `name` attribute for your spans and then you could do the following :

```js
// OVERWRITES old selecor
jQuery.expr[':'].contains = function(a, i, m) {
  return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase()
    .indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
};

function searchClients() {
  var clientSearch = document.getElementById("clientSearch");
  var s = clientSearch.value;
  $('.select-options span').hide();
  $('.select-options span[name^="' + s + '" i]').show();
  if(s == '') $('.select-options span').show()
}

$("#clientSearch").keyup(function() {
  searchClients();
});
```

```css
span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<div class="select-options ps-container below ps-active-y">

  <input id="clientSearch" type="text">

  <span name="bitcoin">Bitcoin</span>
  <span name="cat">Cat</span>
  <span name="whiskey">Whiskey</span>
  <span name="table">Table</span>

</div>
```

You basically hide everything by default and only show the ones that corresponds to your search criteria's name by using :

```
.select-options span[name^="' + s + '" i]
```

This is selecting the span elements inside your class that starts with a certain name. Notice the `i` at the end, it's to specify that's it's case insensitive. So you could either write `cat` or `CaT` in the search box and you'd end up with the same result.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `RegExp`'s `test(str)` method. In Regular Expression, The caret `^` matches at the beginning of the string.

```
 function searchClients() {
   var clientSearch = document.getElementById("clientSearch");
   var s = clientSearch.value;
   $("span").show();
   $("span").filter(function () {
    return !(new RegExp('^'+(s).toUpperCase()))
       .test((this.textContent || this.innerText || '').toUpperCase());
   }).hide();
 }
```

Replace your method `searchClients` with the above function. This way you do not need to add anything on your existing html template. We are simply selecting all the *span*'s to show them by default and then hiding all that does not match the current search input.

Take note of the additional `toUpperCase()` for case insensitivity. You can remove them if you want your search input to be case sensitive.

We are also using `.filter` method instead of the `contains` selector.

To avoid having to modify your existing html template (e.g. having to add additional attributes like a `name` or `id` to your span to provide a search lookup), we are using `textContent` and/or `innerText` to read the inner html content of the *span*'s.

http://jsfiddle.net/apappas1129/xahbL8u6/2/

Comment: No need to use regex here

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy Thank you for pointing that out. I edited my answer to remove the JS example as it does not directly relate to the main problem.